# htaccess rewrite and redirect php extension

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

How can I rewrite & redirect from:

`site.com/folder/login.php` to `site.com/folder/login/`

`site.com/folder/profile.php` to `site.com/folder/profile/`

And I also want when I go to login.php, redirect to `/login/`

I've heared about htaccess, but I'm newbie, can somebody explain how to do this? Thanks in advance

P.S I have `site.com/folder/profile.php?logout=true` Would be good to rewrite this to `site.com/folder/profile/logout/` Thank you.

Comment: Looks like a job for mod_rewrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hiding .php extension from browser**

To hide the .php extension from appearing you should add this inside your .htaccess file!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Now, users can access your page by writing domain.com/profile

I hope this helped you. Good luck!